# Visual Basic Office: Make form that send data to textbox in document

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word, ms-office

So in a Word document I have a form that has  combobox1 with items and I have a button.When I press the button the selected value of combobox should be added at the textbox1 that is in the word document
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGXsP.png)
TextBox1 is not recognized by the form only if I add the text box in the form but I need the text box in document

Also the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & ComboBox1.Text & "*"
End Sub
```

So ComboBox1 is in form and TextBox2 is in word document

Edit:
Form code :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisDocument.TextBox4.Value = ThisDocument.TextBox4.Value + Me.ComboBox1.Text & "*"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("test1", "test2")
End Sub
```

This document:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you trying to pass the information?  Post your code attempt and we can help guide you...

Comment: @Dave Look here is a screenshot with the code http://i.imgur.com/6Hj478X.png

Comment: Can't access that URL from work PC - better to edit your post and insert the code itself

Comment: @Dave I changed the picture link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the textbox value within the document itself; it's currently assuming the parent object is the form you are setting from:

```
ThisDocument.TextBox2.Text = ThisDocument.TextBox2.Text & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "*"
```

Comment: At the second ThisDocument.TextBox2.Text I get method not found

Comment: Method or data membered not found and it points to this 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() and second TextBox2  I think that it can't find data in textbox2 but it should have default value,no?

Comment: That depends if you set one or not :)

Comment: At text I set ' ' but should work also without any value cuz the .text should return null character not an error

Comment: Indeed.  I've just replicated your code inside a Word 2010 document (the only version I have available) and it's working without any issues or errors here.  It shouldn't throw an error on the second use of the textbox if it's not going to do it on the first.  No chance you have a typo in the second use that's not in the first?

Comment: I added a clean TextBox1 and if I deleted second textbox1.text I get on the first one error,ThisDocument found the textbox but seems that it can't select it..Edit:I also tried with value instead of text but the error is the same

Comment: What type of textbox is it that you added to the document?  Did you add it as an activeX object?

Comment: Yes is from ActiveX group

Comment: You may need to post up all the userform code as well as any code you have in the document itself; I can't see from what you have provided so far any reason why this wouldn't work

Comment: Even with copying your code to my document from the post above, it works fine.  Check what references you have enabled in VBA under Tools-->References (maybe something's missing from there for some reason!)

Comment: I got vb for application,Ms word 15.0 object library,OLE Automation,Ms office 15.0 object library,Ms ford 2.0 object library checked :(

Comment: Nope, nothing missing there that I can see.  My configuration also has a reference to Normal, but that's because my Normal template has code in it.  Afraid I've no further advice to offer...

Comment: I made also a new word document and added textbox1 and the form is saved but I still get the same error,a lot of times the same code has different result and this confuse me a lot

Comment: Man,your textbox1 is in document no? I mean in word document,not in the form

Comment: Yep.  TextBox1 was added to the Document rather than being on the UserForm.

Comment: I think that the problem was in the project.I think that I called objects from different projects.Thanks again for all your help